# Why is jstack is unable to get the threadump of a Java process process?

Tags: java, java-8

I am cluless about JSTACK is being unable to get thread dump of a process. It is retuning errors "java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to deduce type of thread from address... "

I tried  below commands:

```
$ sudo bin/jstack   42846
$ sudo bin/jstack -F 42846
```

Any clue will really help me. Below are the errors I am encountering:

```
 Attaching to process ID 42846, please wait...
    Debugger attached successfully.
    Server compiler detected.
    JVM version is 25.131-b11
    Deadlock Detection:

    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to deduce type of thread from address 0x00007fb1f430f000 (expected type JavaThread, CompilerThread, ServiceThread, JvmtiAgentThread, or SurrogateLockerThread)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.runtime.Threads.createJavaThreadWrapper(Threads.java:166)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.runtime.Threads.first(Threads.java:150)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.runtime.DeadlockDetector.createThreadTable(DeadlockDetector.java:149)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.runtime.DeadlockDetector.print(DeadlockDetector.java:56)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.runtime.DeadlockDetector.print(DeadlockDetector.java:39)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.StackTrace.run(StackTrace.java:62)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.StackTrace.run(StackTrace.java:45)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.JStack.run(JStack.java:66)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.Tool.startInternal(Tool.java:260)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.Tool.start(Tool.java:223)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.Tool.execute(Tool.java:118)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.JStack.main(JStack.java:92)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at sun.tools.jstack.JStack.runJStackTool(JStack.java:140)
        at sun.tools.jstack.JStack.main(JStack.java:106)
    Caused by: sun.jvm.hotspot.types.WrongTypeException: No suitable match for type of address 0x00007fb1f430f000
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.runtime.InstanceConstructor.newWrongTypeException(InstanceConstructor.java:62)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.runtime.VirtualConstructor.instantiateWrapperFor(VirtualConstructor.java:80)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.runtime.Threads.createJavaThreadWrapper(Threads.java:162)
        ... 17 more
    Can't print deadlocks:Unable to deduce type of thread from address 0x00007fb1f430f000 (expected type JavaThread, CompilerThread, ServiceThread, JvmtiAgentThread, or SurrogateLockerThread)
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at sun.tools.jstack.JStack.runJStackTool(JStack.java:140)
        at sun.tools.jstack.JStack.main(JStack.java:106)
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to deduce type of thread from address 0x00007fb1f430f000 (expected type JavaThread, CompilerThread, ServiceThread, JvmtiAgentThread, or SurrogateLockerThread)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.runtime.Threads.createJavaThreadWrapper(Threads.java:166)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.runtime.Threads.first(Threads.java:150)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.StackTrace.run(StackTrace.java:75)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.StackTrace.run(StackTrace.java:45)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.JStack.run(JStack.java:66)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.Tool.startInternal(Tool.java:260)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.Tool.start(Tool.java:223)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.Tool.execute(Tool.java:118)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.JStack.main(JStack.java:92)
        ... 6 more
    Caused by: sun.jvm.hotspot.types.WrongTypeException: No suitable match for type of address 0x00007fb1f430f000
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.runtime.InstanceConstructor.newWrongTypeException(InstanceConstructor.java:62)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.runtime.VirtualConstructor.instantiateWrapperFor(VirtualConstructor.java:80)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.runtime.Threads.createJavaThreadWrapper(Threads.java:162)
```

Answer (score 9):

Actually, it worked when I run the jstack command as the owner of the process. I was running jstack as root user and the process I was trying to take thread dump was a Cassandra DB process. Owner of the process was "cassandra" user and when I run the "jstack" command from "cassandra" user, everything worked.

But the jstack error output should have been able to indicate that issue, unfortunately it spews out something different.

Answer (score 2):

Another option might be missing debuginfo on CentOS, I've solved it by

```
#debuginfo-install java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.181-3.b13.el7_5.x86_64
```

Comment: Check java version `java -version` and you don't have to give the full version, this worked for me: 
`debuginfo-install java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.144`.  After that as root user I could get stack trace of jenkins user java process.